# Conversión entre bases (Conversion between bases)

Tags: numerical-methods

¿Es cierto que todo número que tiene una representación finita en base 3 tambien tiene una representacion finita en base $3^k$ con $k\in\mathbb N$? ¿ Por qué?

English version: Is it true that every number that has a finite representation in base 3 also has a finite representation in base $3^k$ with $k \in \mathbb N$? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Sì e la rappresentazione in base $3^k$ si può recuperare da quella in base $3$ nel seguente modo:

- aggiungi zeri in coda ai decimali finché il numero di cifre dopo la virgola non diventa multiplo di $k$;
- raggruppa $k$ a $k$ le cifre dopo la virgola partendo da sinistra. Lo $n$-esimo gruppetto in base $3$ diventerà una singola cifra in base $3^k$, che rappresenterà la cifra del decimale $3^{-kn}=(3^k)^{-n}$.

Comment: Did you just answer a question asked in Spanish in Italian? This is probably going to be deleted, but take my +1 anyway, haha.

Comment: Whatever. I most certainly can't answer in Spanish.

Comment: estoy intentando traducirlo graciass por responder